# How to PHP cURL to SurveyMonkey API?

Tags: php, http, curl, surveymonkey

I am trying to use PHP cURL to retrieve some data from SurveyMonkey's API and I keep getting a 500 error.

Here is my code:

```
  $requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
  );

  $baseUrl = 'https://api.surveymonkey.net';
  $endpoint = '/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

  $fields = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'title','analysis_url','date_created','date_modified'
    )
  );

  $fieldsString = json_encode($fields);

  $ch  = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl . $endpoint);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
```

The response I get is

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "request_id": "e0c10adf-ae8f-467d-83af-151e8e229618",
    "error": {
        "message": "Server busy, please try again later."
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on the command line:

```
curl -H 'Authorization:bearer XXXXX' 
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=XXXXXXXX 
--data-binary '{"fields":["title","analysis_url","date_created","date_modified"]}'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you with a 500 error. Have you contacted Surveymonkey?

Comment: I haven't. Since my command line curl works, I assumed I'm doing something wrong with php cURL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, but there are a couple small mistakes.

First, while you do specify the `Content-Type` correctly (`application/json`), you have not specified the `Content-Length`.

Make this change to `$requestHeaders` and move it **below** the creation of `$fieldsString`:

```
$requestHeaders = array(
     'Content-Type: application/json',
     'Authorization: Bearer ' . $_GET['code'],
     'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fieldsString)
);
```

Second, you have set `CURLOPT_POST` to true. This will force CURL to treat your request as a **form POST** which has a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This will create a problem because SurveyMonkey is expecting the content-type `application/json`.

Remove this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

and replace it with this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't solve it. :\ I ended up using exec() and passing the huge string I typed on the terminal, but it's not a very clean solution. Please let me know if you can think of anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your answer is correct. I just realized that I was missing the step where you exchange the code for an access token. Thank you so much!